# Initializing scripts in wordpress

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to initialize a script in wordpress. So far I've added the following to my theme:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {   
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'stellar.js', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/stellar.js', 
        array('jquery'), 
        '1.0.0', 
        true 
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adv_scripts' );
```

It was my understanding that this would load the script. Unfortunately it doesn't and I still need to add the following in the header.php

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/stellar.js"></script>
```

It's a similar story for jquery too, where I have to manually add it to the header.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

And this in the functions.php

```
function my_scripts_method() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `wp_head` and `wp_footer`

Comment: In your first bit of code the function name doesn't match the `add_action`, is that a typo?

Comment: I thought the last bit of the add_action was you just make up a name. That's what all the guides say, to add the name of your theme. In my case that is 'adv' - confused. Yes I have wp-head and wp_footer added in my theme.

Comment: The last bit of `add_action` needs to be the name of the function, so in your first bit of code it should be `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );`